# Providing an own set of POIs to Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a user-scenario in which a dedicated set of point-of-interests (POI) should be searched/visualized/routed-to in Google Maps or Microsoft Bing. Since all of the functionality is provided by all major built-in map-applications, I'm curious if I can somewhat solve this problem by one of these three options.

1. **Custom Android App:** Implement a map that uses Google Maps activity and retrieves the POIs from a custom backend.
2. **Android Service:** a service without a front-end that provides the POIs as a searchable ContentProvider. The user may search for the POI and visualize it in the built-in Google Maps app.
3. **Whitelabeled app:** existing app extended by list of POIs. But which one?
4. **Any other option:** is there any other way to provide custom POIs to Google Maps on the phone?

Glad for your input to the discussion.